How to get back the gnome panel on the left side?
Using 24.04 I made some removes and upgrades, and I was not carefully enough. Now the panel on the left side is gone. There is a dock on the bottom, that appears when I hit the super button, but this is not what I want. What do I have to do to get panel back on the left side as it was before?
Best regards
Martin

Did you try disabling "Auto-hide the Dock" option under Settings -> Ubuntu Desktop??

Go to Settings > Ubuntu Desktop > Dock > Position on screen. There are three options: Bottom, left, and right. Copied from this Q&A

Under settings -> Ubuntu Desktop -> there are only three entries:

Size
Position of new icons
Show home folder

